# Can someone look at my loop?

Tags: python-3.x

guys I have no idea what is wrong with my loop but I keep on getting an error that my last line is not indented properly , i have tried indenting it multiple times but keep on getting the error.

```
while itemsneeded>=1:
    if (items[0]) == 86947367 :
        with open("read_it.txt") as text_file:
            try:
                price = int(text_file.readlines()[2])
            except ValueError:
                print("error")
            else:
                new_price = int(price * (items2[0]))
                print("£",new_price)

    elif (items[0]) == 78364721 :
        with open("read_it.txt") as text_file:
            try:
                price = int(text_file.readlines()[6])
            except ValueError:
                print("error")
            else:
                new_price = int(price * (items2[0]))
                print("£",new_price)

    elif (items[0]) == 35619833 :
        with open("read_it.txt") as text_file:
            try:
                price = int(text_file.readlines()[10])
            except ValueError:
                print("error")
            else:
                new_price = int(price * (items2[0]))
                print("£",new_price)

    elif (items[0]) == 84716491  :
        with open("read_it.txt") as text_file:
            try:
                price = int(text_file.readlines()[14])
            except ValueError:
                print("error")
            else:
                new_price = int(price * (items2[0]))
                print("£",new_price)

    elif (items[0]) == 46389121  :
        with open("read_it.txt") as text_file:
            try:
                price = int(text_file.readlines()[18])
            except ValueError:
                print("error")
            else:
                new_price = int(price * (items2[0]))
                print("£",new_price)
else:
    continue
```

I want my code to continue if itemsneeded is not equal to 1 or more.

Comment: *All* of your lines except the first one are not indented properly. Add one tab/shift to them.

Comment: you mean the second one ?

Comment: did that , still error.

Comment: `itemspeed` is not modified in the loop. Using it in the loop condition makes no sense.

Comment: itemspeed ????? , if you mean itemsneeded , I have.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is `continue` within your last `else` clause. It's not needed as there's no iterator to continue with. As soon as your program leaves the `while` loop it moves on anyways.

Remove the last two lines.

```
else:
    continue
```

Comment: Or change the last line to `pass`

Comment: @jgritty This is true, it all depends on how this block of code is implemented. If this is a snippet from within a function you could simply `return` at that point.

Comment: I wanted my program to "skip" the loop if itemsneeded was not bigger than or equal to 1.

Comment: if i remove the else : continue , python just loops the answer forever.